# Google MAP does not appear unless PF12 is pressed

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

I have an application with a google map being included inside a ReactJs application.
I cannot see the map [Just the Google logo and a grey background] unless the PF12 is pressed
When I get into debugging mode or when I leave the debugging mode, the map appears.
The PF12 seems to solve the problem of map being absent which is strange....
It does not seem to be related to the key being generated for the debug mode as if I stay in debug mode and go back to my map page, I cannot display the map until the PF12 is pressed and the debug console disappears.....
Pressing PF12 to go on debug mode or to leave the debug mode makes the map appear but I have no idea why !
An event issue ?
For example, the map jsx file is quite simple:

```
export class BasicMap extends React.Component {
....
 render() {
    return (
      <div style={style}>
        <Map
        google={this.props.google}
          style={{width: '570px', height: '400px', position: 'relative'}}
          className={'map'}
          zoom={5}
          containerStyle={{}}>
            <Marker
          name={'SOMA'}
          position={{lat: -33.8907066882, lng: 150.877077}}
          onClick={this.onMarkerClick.bind(this)}
          />
    </div>
export default GoogleApiComponent({
  apiKey: "..."
})(BasicMap)
```

And the package.json

```
  "name": "react-test-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.7.0",
    "babel-cli": "6.16.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.16.0",
    "body-parser": "1.15.2",
    "express": "4.14.0",
    "google-map-react": "0.22.3",
    "google-maps-react": "1.0.19",
    "history": "4.4.0",
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "15.3.2",
    "react-google-maps": "6.0.1",
    "react-history": "0.15.1",
    "react-router": "3.0.0",
    "webpack": "1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.14.1"
  },
```

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code so we can help you.

Comment: I thought it was more a problem with the configuration but not wwith the code as I tried with two different examples I got the same result. For example, the map jsx file is :                                                                       export class BasicMap extends React.Component {